How can I detect when a git custom command script is being run as `git foo`?
When git is invoked with an unrecognized first parameter, e.g. git foo, it looks on the path for an executable git-foo and runs that if found.
If I create git-foo as a shell script and print $0 in that script, I get the path and name of the script file, which is normal. In a shell script it is common to print basename "$0" to refer to the script itself, and this might be used in "Usage" or "Example" section of the output. However, in this case, the default $0 behavior is not desired. I would like to output git-foo if the script is run manually, but in the expected case of it being invoked as git foo I want to output git foo in those places.
How can I detect when this is appropriate? I've checked the environment around my script and there doesn't seem to be any var set by git to tell the child about the invocation (nothing relevant containing git or foo or GIT). Do I need OS-specific functionality to get the invocation of the parent process if it exists?

When executed by git, I see GIT_EXEC_PATH in the environment.

@WilliamPursell that's the best option I have so far, but it would also trigger if someone/thing explicitly sets that in order to change git's behavior and then also runs one of the scripts directly

is your sole purpose to write git-foo (or git foo) in information messages such as "Usage" or "Example" sections ? I would suggest to choose one of the two strings and always display that.

You could try and check the parent process (tested on Windows or Linux).
I have a C:\Users\vonc\home_senv\bin\git-t file, which can tell how it is called:
#!/bin/bash

parent_process=""

is_called_by_git() {
    if ! parent_process=$(ps -o comm= -p $PPID 2>/dev/null); then
      parent_process=$(ps -p $PPID -l | awk 'NR==2 {print $4}')
    fi
    if [[ "${parent_process}" == "git" || "${parent_process}" == "" ]]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

name="$(basename "$0")"
if is_called_by_git; then
    echo "Invoked as: ${name//-/ } (parent_process: '${parent_process}')"
else
    echo "Invoked as: path/to/${name}  (parent_process: '${parent_process}')"
fi

Since C:\Users\vonc\home_senv\bin is in my %PATH%, I can call it with (using cygwin):
C:\Users\vonc\home_senv>bash -c "git t"
Invoked as: git t (parent_process: 'git')

C:\Users\vonc\home_senv>bash -c "bin/git-t"
Invoked as: path/to/git-t  (parent_process: 'Relay(18)')

C:\Users\vonc\home_senv>git t
Invoked as: git t (parent_process: '')

And from an Ubuntu (WSL2) session:
vonc@voncfm:~$ /mnt/c/Users/vonc/home_senv/bin/git-t
Invoked as: path/to/git-t  (parent_process: 'bash')
vonc@voncfm:~$ git t
Invoked as: git t (parent_process: 'git')

